# How to count the number of items that exist in a table efficiently with EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, count

I have a C# project in which several items are stored in different tables, for example to count how many elements a table contains I do something similar to the following:

```js
public int getLengthListProducts(int idCompany)
{
  try
  {
      using (var context = new ccoFinalEntities())
      {
        return context.products.Where(p => true == p.status && idCompany == p.idCompany).ToList().Count;
      }
  }
  catch
  {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

So far it has worked very well, but when the amount starts to be 1000 items, on some PCs it starts to take a while to get this number.

I suspect that context.products places all items in RAM and then begins to extract and count those that meet the following conditions and that is why the application is frozen until the count is finished.

My question is: Is there a way to do it better?

For example I thought that I should resort directly to SQL statements instead of using EntityFramework to get that number, but I don't know if that would be a good idea, or if there is a more efficient way with EntityFramework.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: At a guess, remove the `ToList()`

Comment: There's no need for `.Where().ToList().Count`, for starters. Just call `.Count()` directly with your predicate.

Comment: if you do need the ToList() for any other reason, better be the last thing that you do

Comment: suggestion: Your `catch` is kinda crappy, why are you returning `-1`?  Your table probably doesn't contain -1 rows. This way all the callers need to check for result -1? If you can't "fix" the exception here, you should not catch it at this level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
context.products.Where(p => true == p.status && idCompany == p.idCompany).ToList().Count;
```

In this Linq query, `ToList()` will generate the SQL Query :

```
SELECT ...
FROM Products
WHERE status = 1 and idCompagny = @idCompany
```

This query is executed on your database and can return a lot of rows.
All elements is loaded in client's memory in .Net Collection and `Count` return final result.

With Entity Framework, you can use aggregate Linq query (Count, Sum, Avg, ...) :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/aggregate-queries

Example :

```
context.products.Where(p => true == p.status && idCompany == p.idCompany).Count();
```

`Count()` will generate the SQL Query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Products
WHERE status = 1 and idCompagny = @idCompany
```

The query is executed on your database and return scalar result.

Comment: It can be shortened into:
context.products.Count(p => true == p.status && idCompany == p.idCompany);

Comment: It's always better set where condition in Where, this is only for performance...

Answer (score 1):

```
context.products.Count(p => p.status == true && idCompany == p.idCompany);
```

or

```
context.products.Where(p => p.idCompany == idCompany)
                .Count(p => p.status == true);
```

(for readability)

will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server you can do this

```
   string cmd = @"SELECT
        t.NAME AS TableName,
        s.Name AS SchemaName,
        p.rows AS RowCounts,
        SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB,
        SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB,
        (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
    FROM
        sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN
        sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN
        sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE
        t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%'
        AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
    GROUP BY
        t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
    "
    db.Database.SqlQuery(cmd).ToList<Statistic>();
```

with

```
    public class Statistic
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string SchemaName { get; set; }
        public long RowCounts { get; set; }
        public long TotalSpaceKB { get; set; }
        public long UsedSpaceKB { get; set; }
        public long UnusedSpaceKB { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you get a pretty fast overview of all your tables, here including size in memory.

I know hard coded SQL ist not to be prefered, but since its relating to System-Tables only, and wherefore you can assume, they never change, it's acceptable.

Comment: This is not useful for counting the number of rows that match a particular predicate, as used in the original question. It is more useful for maintenance scripts, but even there care should be taken that `sys.partitions.rows` is more or less "best effort" and may on occasion not reflect the actual number of rows (see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55124/97345), for example).

Comment: Maybe, but the question contained the phrase  *to count how many elements a table contains*, so maybe this was of interest. Actually this is using system.partition.rows, just with additional information like the table name, which is not in this table.